# how to set a function to be called after recordForDuration is crossed in iPhone AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

I am using the AVAudioRecorder to record some sound from the mic. I am using [recorder recordForDuration: 10] I want to upload the sound file when 10 second is over. Is there a way to specify this ? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

-
ahsan

Answer (score 3):

Another way  will be to use a Timer function ! :)

[Xcode Objective-C | iOS: delay function / NSTimer help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998764/xcode-objective-c-ios-delay-function-nstimer-help)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the delegate `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:` **only if you send a double, float or NSTimeInterval as the duration of the recording**.

*These **will** trigger the delegate*

```
[recorder recordForDuration:10.0]; // double
[recorder recordForDuration:10.0f]; // float
```

*This **will not** trigger the delegate*

```
[recorder recordForDuration:10]; // int
```

Technically, these should be of the type NSTimeInterval and not float or double.

*Source: @Johnmph comment*

Comment: Why downvote my answer and copy it with my comment to make a new answer ??

Comment: What is really unhelpful, it is to copy / paste an answer a year later and to down vote this answer.

Comment: I don't need credit or source but i just don't like that you down voted my answer. What is wrong in my answer ? Don't you need a delegate to be notified when the recording is done ? Ok for saying that my answer is not complete for this case and to let a new more complete answer but not for down voting my answer. Down vote an answer if it is wrong not if it is not complete.

Comment: I didn't learn anything from your fight, i tested all of your cases, and none of them is triggering the audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate of the AVAudioRecorder object.

The delegate will receive the message audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully: when the recording is done.

See documentation of AVAudioRecorder :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioRecorder

and AVAudioRecorderDelegate :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorderDelegate_ProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAudioRecorderDelegate

Comment: This is what I did, added - (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{NSLog (@"Done");}  .. however I dont get any output :(.. any help ? (I also added  [self.recorder.delegate self]; )

Comment: none of the following works !!   recorder.delegate=self;   or   [recorder setDelegate:self];

Comment: the delegate functions work only if I explicitly use [recorder stop]...not if I use   [recorder recordForDuration: 10] ..any help ?

Comment: @Ahsan, recordForDuration requires a NSTimeInterval (which is a double value) and you pass an int value, maybe that's the problem.
If that doesn't work also, you can use record instead recordForTime and immediatly after create a nstimer which will call stop method after time of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Swift code for recording for 10 seconds:

```
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder! 
    var meterTimer: NSTimer?

    func btnRecordAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let currentDateTime = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let recordingName = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime)+".m4a"
    let filePath = self.docPath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent(recordingName)

    var error: NSError?
    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: .DuckOthers, error: &error)

    let recordSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 
    ]

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: url, settings: recordSettings as! [NSObject : AnyObject] , error: &error)
    if let e = error {
        println("AVAudioRecorder error = \(e.localizedDescription)" )
    } else {
        self.audioRecorder.delegate = self
        self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        self.audioRecorder.recordForDuration(10.0)
        self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        self.audioRecorder.record()

        if self.audioRecorder.recording == true {
            self.meterTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1,
                target:self,
                selector:"updateAudioMeter:",
                userInfo:nil,
                repeats:true)
        }
    }
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
        println("finished recording \(flag)")


        // ios8 and later
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Recorder",
            message: "Finished Recording",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Keep", style: .Default, handler: {action in
            println("keep was tapped")
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default, handler: {action in
            self.audioRecorder?.deleteRecording()
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
}

func audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!,
    error: NSError!) {
        println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}

func updateAudioMeter(timer:NSTimer) {

    if  self.audioRecorder.recording {
        let dFormat = "%02d"
        let min:Int = Int(self.audioRecorder.currentTime / 60)
        let sec:Int = Int(self.audioRecorder.currentTime % 60)
        let s = "Recording: \(String(format: dFormat, min)):\(String(format: dFormat, sec)) secs"
        self.lblRecorderTime!.text = s
        self.audioRecorder.updateMeters()

    }

}
```